# Expected value of ith sample versus expected value of a random variable

Tags: expected-value, sample

Consider a random variable $X$.

When we talk about the expected value of the random variable $X$, we use the notation $\mathbb{E}\left(X\right)$.

However, I found that, in introductory statistics textbooks, they use a notation $\mathbb{E}\left(X_i\right)$, and I am not sure what is the exact meaning of that.

In my guess, when we consider a random sample of $X$, $[X_i]_{i=1,\ldots,N}$, each $X_i$ is a random variable, and thus $\mathbb{E}\left(X_i\right)$ is a valid notation.

Then, what is the exact difference between $\mathbb{E}\left(X\right)$ and $\mathbb{E}\left(X_i\right)$?

I think, if we assume that the sample is "randomly" drawn, $\mathbb{E}\left(X_1\right)=\ldots=\mathbb{E}\left(X_N\right)$, and so we can omit the subscript $i$.

But, I am not sure, it is a correct explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite right, "simple random sample" is often taken to be "iid", i.e., independently and *identically* distributed. And if the r.v.s have the same distribution they a fortiori have the same expected value.

Especially in mathematical statistics sources, you will also find the notation $EX_1=\mu$, which is to be taken to read that if we can (arbitrarily) look at the distribution of the first r.v., then the others will have the same distribution/expected value.